# Video within a JQuery Slider

Tags: html, video, flash, jquery

I am just starting development on a JQuery Slider that will start with a video, and when the video is done the slider will begin.  I'd like for the site to be able to work on both IE9 and lower, and the iPhone, which I assume will require an HTML5 option and a Flash option.  I would like the slider to look like this:

http://popstache.com/

with a minimal UI, just the arrows and circles on the bottom allowing for slide selection.

I have been playing with Slidedeck at http://www.slidedeck.com/, and I know that videos can be embedded in it.  My main concern right now is the video.  I've heard about people using Flowplayer, but I'd rather not pay the $95 to remove the branding, and I do not believe that will work on the iPhone.  Any suggestions?  Thank you.

Comment: There's no such thing as just "IE." Specify a minimum version, please. And, you realize Slidedeck's also branded, and costs about the same as the player to remove it, right?

Comment: I'm sorry I wasn't more clear.  When I said IE, I meant IE 9 and earlier, which, to my understanding, does not support HTML5.  I did not realize that Slidedeck is branded, thank you for bringing that to my attention.

Comment: Depending on what you're doing with the slider, you may run into problems, at least with the Flash fallback. Displaying anything on top of a plugin often doesn't work. Moving a plugin in the DOM often resets its state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MediaFront's [OSM Player](http://www.mediafront.org/project/osmplayer) is completely free.

So is [jPlayer](http://www.jplayer.org/).

Comment: I will look into those options.  Thank you.

Comment: I tested. The OSM Player does not work well in IE 9. The JPlayer work awesome except is does not have snapshot like FlowPlayer.